# okhttp3 minifyEnabled causes crash on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, proguard, okhttp

This code in `okhttp:3.12.13` works fine with `minifyEnabled false`

```
  private static boolean supportsAlpn() {
    if (Security.getProvider("GMSCore_OpenSSL") != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      try {
        Class.forName("android.net.Network"); //NoClassDefFoundError here if minifyEnabled true
        return true;
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) { }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

but with `minifyEnabled true` the following error occurs on Android 4.1.2

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:292)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:258)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:231)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.supportsAlpn(AndroidPlatform.java:219)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:262)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findAndroidPlatform(Platform.java:246)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at android.net.Network.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

What lines should be added to `Proguard` to avoid the crash?

**Edit:**
Adding rules [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro) and [2](https://github.com/square/okio/blob/master/okio/src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/proguard/okio.pro) didn't help.

[These rules](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-okhttp3.pro) worked, but apk size gets increased by 0.6 MB.

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to fix the issue without keeping all `okhttp3` classes in the apk.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rules from below files/links

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/okhttp/src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro
https://github.com/square/okio/blob/master/okio/src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/proguard/okio.pro

Refer
https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/r8_proguard/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an identical problem on Android 4.1.1 with OkHttp 3.12.12 but the suggest fix to proguard rules did not correct my issue.

Interesting to note that the NoClassDefFoundError appears to be coming from a copy of android.net.Network that is bundled in the APK by r8 but contains the following unusual code (disassembled with apktool):

```
.class public synthetic Landroid/net/Network;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;

# interfaces
.implements Landroid/os/Parcelable;


# direct methods
.method static synthetic constructor <clinit>()V
    .locals 1

    new-instance v0, Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError;-><init>()V

    throw v0
.end method
```

This is why the NoClassDefFoundError has no message and originates from clinit (static initializer).

This is a fairly wild guess but perhaps r8 generates this code internally for the minify phase and then accidentally materializes it into the APK? So it appears this is likely some kind of bug in r8.

Regardless the fix that actually worked was to not use Android Gradle plugin 7.3.X and instead revert to AGP 7.2.2. AGP 7.4.0-beta04 also appears to work. With these other version of AGP the unsual android.net.Network class does not appear in the APK.

Comment: The `android.net.Network` is placed in the APK by design. When you get that `NoClassDefFoundError` from the generated `<clinit>` the app is trying to use a class which is not present on the device. The code is missing an API level check - or does not support Android 4.1. WIthout the `android.net.Network` class in the APK the `NoClassDefFoundError` would still have happened as the class does not exist on Android 4.1. Please see https://issuetracker.google.com/258270051#comment2 for details.

Comment: @sgjesse Thanks for following up with Google on this, it looks like they acknowledged the bug and are working on it, l will keep an eye on it.